# How to decide whether to store deep documents or thin related documents in a NoSQL database

Tags: mongodb, database-design, web-applications, nosql

### New To NoSQL

In my 8 years of web development I've always used a relational database. Recently I started using MongoDB for a simple, multi-user web app where users can create their own photo galleries.

### My Domain

My Domain is quite simple, there are "users" > "sites" > "photo sets" > "photos".

I've been struggling on how to decide how to store these documents. In the application sometimes I only need a small collection of "photos", and sometimes only the "sets", but always I need some information about the "user", and possibly the "site".

### Thin Versus Deep

Currently I'm storing multiple thin documents, using my own implementation of foreign keys. The problem of course is that I sometimes have to make multiple calls to Mongo to render a single page.

### Questions

Of course I'm sure there are ways to get around these inefficiencies, caches etc, but how do NoSQLers approach these problems:

- Is it normal to related your documents like this?
- Is it better to just store potentially massive deep documents?
- Am I getting it wrong, and actually I should be storing multiple documents specifically for different views?
- If you're storing multiple documents for different views, how do you manage updates?
- Is the answer to use the "embed" features of Mongo? Is that how most solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinks to think about when using a NoSQL Database, especially MongoDB:

How you manipulate the data?

- Dynamic Queries
- Secondary Indexes
- Atomic Updates
- Map Reduce

What about your Access Patterns (per Collection)?

- Read / Write Ratio
- Types of updates
- Types of queries
- Data life-cycle

Basic Knowledge:

- Document writes are atomic
- Maximum Document Size is 16Meg (with GridFS you could store larger files too)

Watch out for:

- Careless Indexing
- Large, deeply nested documents

Here=s an older talk about Schema Design: [Schema Design Basics](http://www.scribd.com/doc/37943580/MongoDB-schema-design-basics)

Comment: +1 Hey Marc, great advice. I guess the point is, documents shouldn't be too large, so that answers that question... but still, how do decrease the amount of reads from the db, or does it not matter?

Comment: as always: it depends, if your db is small and fits in RAM (including indexes) then it kind of really doesn't matter. If not, well then it fully depends on which documents are you requesting and how often (access patterns). MongoDB is using MemoryMapped Files as File Persistance. If you have 10 TB of Data but only need the last two Days (a.k.a Working Set) which is probably less than your systems memory, then your data will be in RAM.

Comment: interesting... thanks. So, the smaller your documents are, the more chance there is of them being in RAM...? So you're saying more calls to RAM are better than less calls to disk right?

Comment: there is of course an storage overhead for the index per document :) but yes, RAM is always better than disc. and since MongoDB is using memory mapped files, it highly scales with ram and fast disc IO. (for calls not in active set or full collection scans)